# gSoap isn't including the Envelope and Body opening tags

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

The way I'm currently using gSoap, is:

```
soap_init(soapObj);
soap_new_set__ns1__CheckServer(soapObj);
soap_call__ns1__CheckServer(soapObj, NULL, NULL, objCheckServer, objResponse);
```

And after checking the SENT.log, i can see that the envelope that we're sending doesn't contain the `<SOAP-ENV: Envelope>`, `<SOAP-ENV: Header>`, or the `<SOAP-ENV: Body>` tag. It just starts with `<ns1: CheckServer>` and begins declaring name spaces. Is there an initialization that we're missing or is this code just buggy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that fixed it was to set the version.

```
soap_set_version(soapObj, 2)
```